# CellforItemAtIndexPath not getting called in GMGridview for paging?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, gmgridview

I have used the GMGridView in my App.

I have used the HorizontalLTB layout strategy for paging but when i swipe from the first page to the second page the method CellforItemAtIndexPath is not getting called.

But when i swipe from page 2 to page 3 the method is called, I want to set the dots as per the offset so i need to call this method.

What could be the solution ?

Comment: Can you please put your code over here?

Comment: Put in some code of yours, so that we can help you out.